# Access a remote api from frontend react.js without any server side code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, fetch-api, remoteapi

I am trying to access remote URL from fetch/axios post API in react.js. Here is my code in react-

```
  const requestOptions = {
        method: 'POST', 
        crossDomain: true,
        mode: 'cors', // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        credentials: 'same-origin', // include, *same-origin, omit              
        headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT'},
        redirect: 'follow', // manual, *follow, error 
        referrerPolicy: 'no-referrer', 
        body:new URLSearchParams({
            'store_id':'storeid',
            'store_passwd':'storepass',
            'total_amount':100,
            'currency':'BDT',
            'tran_id':'NF04',
            'success_url':"https://tigrow.herokuapp.com",
            'fail_url':"https://tigrow.herokuapp.com",
            'cancel_url':"https://tigrow.herokuapp.com",
            'cus_name':"nizam",
            'cus_email':"test@test.com",
            'cus_add1':"customer address",
            'cus_add2':"customer address",
            'cus_city':"Dhaka",
            'cus_state':"Dhaka2",
            'cus_postcode':"Dhaka",
            'cus_country':"Bangladesh",
            'cus_phone':"01700000000",
            'cus_fax':"01700000000",
            'ship_name':"Sha",
            'ship_add1':"dhaka",
            'ship_add2':"dhaka1",
            'ship_city':"Dhaka1",
            'ship_state':"Dhaka2",
            'ship_postcode':"1000",
            'ship_country':"Bangladesh",
            'multi_card_name':"mastercard,visacard,amexcard",
            'value_a':"ref001_A",
            'value_b':"ref002_B",
            'value_c':"ref003_C",
            'value_d':"ref004_D",
            'shipping_method':"No",
            'product_name':"Test",
            'product_category':"Test Category",
            'product_profile':"general"
        })
    };           
    fetch(url, requestOptions)
        .then(response =>console.log(response))
        .then(data => console.log(data));
```

I want to get data from remote API in react only, not any server side code. Here my content-type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded. How can I solve this problem only using react.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My remote API strictly mentioned that no call from client side code. Developer must need to call the API from server side and after completing the call developer should return the string url, not any json data. I followed the way and done the code in python and got the result. However my frontend was react. Here is the code snippet-

```
def sslcommerz_payment_gateway(request):    
    gateway_auth_details = PaymentGatewaySettings.objects.all().first()
    settings = {'store_id':gateway_auth_details.store_id,
            'store_pass': gateway_auth_details.store_pass,
            'issandbox': True} #gateway_auth_details.store_pass, 'issandbox': False}     
    print(request.POST)    
    sslcommez = SSLCOMMERZ(settings)
    post_body = {}
    post_body['total_amount'] =request.POST.get('total_amount')
    post_body['currency'] = request.POST.get('currency')
    post_body['tran_id'] =unique_transaction_id_generator()
    post_body['success_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payment/success/'
    post_body['fail_url'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/payment/faild/'
    post_body['cancel_url'] = request.POST.get('cancel_url')
    post_body['emi_option'] = 0
    post_body['cus_name'] = request.POST.get('cus_name')
    post_body['cus_email'] =request.POST.get("cus_email")
    post_body['cus_phone'] = request.POST.get("cus_phone")
    post_body['cus_add1'] = request.POST.get("cus_add1")
    post_body['cus_city'] = request.POST.get("cus_city")
    post_body['cus_state'] =request.POST.get("cus_state")
    post_body['cus_postcode'] =request.POST.get("cus_postcode")
    post_body['cus_country'] = request.POST.get("cus_country")
    post_body['shipping_method'] ="NO"#request.POST.get("shipping_method")       
    post_body['multi_card_name'] = "mastercard,visacard,amexcard,mobilebank,internetbank,othercard"
    post_body['num_of_item'] = request.POST.get("num_of_item")
    post_body['product_name'] = request.POST.get("product_name")
    post_body['product_category'] = request.POST.get("product_category")
    post_body['product_profile'] = "Art(Hard Copy/Soft Copy)"   
    response = sslcommez.createSession(post_body) 
    print(response)        
    return 'https://sandbox.sslcommerz.com/gwprocess/v4/gw.php?Q=pay&SESSIONKEY=' + response["sessionkey"]
```

Finally I got the API response and returned a url.